# How can I get the Git commit hash in my PS script?

Tags: git, powershell, msbuild

I'm using a PowerShell script to call `msbuild` and pass in a version number to OctopusDeploy like this:

```
msbuild "Xyz.sln" /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:RunOctoPack=true /p:OctopackPackageVersion=$versionNumber
```

... where $versionNumber is generated in the PS script.  What I want to do is add the first 16 characters of the Git commit hash to the end of the version string so it will end up looking like:

```
2.yyyyMMdd.HHmmss-git-6d34e44340f95c2a
```

How can I do this?  Can I get `msbuild` or Visual Studio to return the current git commit hash somehow, considering they now have built-in Git support?

Comment: If you want to manage versioning with git and .Net, feel free to have a look to GitVersion https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion that help you do semantic versioning (good practice!). There is even a msbuild task... Time stamp is not a very good practice and you should prefer git topology (that gitversion help you to achieve easily)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in the end was just bundle `NGit` next to my Powershell script (files `NGit.dll`, `Sharpen.dll`, and `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll`) then use some code like this to generate the version number with git hash suffixed:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("Ngit.dll") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("Sharpen.dll") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll") | Out-Null

# *** Git repo base path (should contain .sln file) ***
$repoPath = "C:\Path\To\Repo"

# *** OctopusDeploy API key for publishing ***
$octoApiKey = "API-[PublishKey]"

#######################################################

# *** Get and process current Git commit hash ***
$sharpenRepoPath = New-Object -TypeName Sharpen.FilePath -ArgumentList "$($repoPath)\.git"
$repoBuilder = New-Object -TypeName NGit.RepositoryBuilder
$repo = $repoBuilder.SetGitDir($sharpenRepoPath).Build()
$headHash = $repo.Resolve("HEAD").Name.Substring(0,12)

# *** Version when pushing to OctopusDeploy NuGet ***
$versionNumber = "2." + [datetime]::now.tostring("yyyyMMdd.HHmmss") + "-git-" + $headHash

# *** Pause before publish ****
Write-Host "About to publish to OctopusDeploy NuGet with version number:"
Write-Host "    $($versionNumber)"
cmd /c pause

# *** OctopusDeploy build and push ***
msbuild "$repoPath\MySolution.sln" /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:RunOctoPack=true /p:OctopackPackageVersion=$versionNumber /p:OctoPackPublishPackageToHttp=https://my.nuget.server/nuget/packages /p:OctoPackPublishApiKey=$octoApiKey
```

Answer (score 14):

You can actually do this directly in msbuild so that it works from VS and most CI systems without any extra steps (e.g. PowerShell scripts), even on the cross-platform `dotnet` CLI and mono.

You can create a file named `Directory.Build.targets` in the project or solution (> affects all projects) directory with the following contents (assuming MSBuild 15 / VS 2017. if lower, you'll need manual imports or insert this target into every project)

```
<Project>
  <Target Name="DetermineOctopackVersion" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(RunOctoPack)' == 'true' ">
    <Exec Command="git rev-parse HEAD" ConsoleToMSBuild="true" StandardOutputImportance="low">
      <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="GitCommitHash" />
    </Exec>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <VersionDatePart>$([System.DateTime]::get_Now().ToString(yyyyMMdd.HHmmss))</VersionDatePart>
      <OctopackPackageVersion>2.$(VersionDatePart)-git-$(GitCommitHash.Substring(0,16))</OctopackPackageVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

If you want the property to be set on every build, not only when `RunOctoPack` is `true`, simply remove the `Condition` attribute.

But if you need to do it in PowerShell, you can call the git command and capture its output:

```
$commitHash = (git rev-parse HEAD).Substring(0,16)
$versionDatePart = [System.DateTime]::Now.ToString('yyyyMMdd.HHmmss')
$version = "1.$versionDatePart-git-$commitHash"
```

If you really want to avoid calling into `git` (though no decent build system setup is complete without a git installation..) you can also use `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(".git\refs\heads\master")` both in PS or MSBuild to read from the git directory (on detached state, `.git\HEAD` will contain the hash, when a branch is used it will contain the location of the file to look for the hash).

Comment: Am I right in thinking that both of your solutions require `git.exe` to be installed on the machine?  That's not an assumption I can make in this scenario.

Comment: best practice is to use the version of git used to set up the build.. you can load libgit# like in the other version or look for the files yourself but i strongly suggest using the `git.exe` approach is it is the most cross-platform one (personally, i don't consider an environment without a git installation not to be a dev or build environment)

Comment: E.g. if you use `dotnet msbuild`, there's no way to download and resolve a LibGit# version that is guaranteed to work in the host runtime (since VS doesn't need to be installed and you could be running on linux)

Comment: What do you mean the git version that is used to "set up the build"?

Answer (score 1):

As you wanted to avoid calling `git.exe` as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802657/how-can-i-extract-git-commit-hash-from-vs-msbuild/43815817) and you want to have the commit processing in PowerShell you can covert the C# solution to PowerShell like this.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\LibGit2Sharp.dll") | Out-Null

$repo = [LibGit2Sharp.Repository]::new("C:\MyRepo")
$repo.Commits | Select-Object -First 1
```

This will return the LibGit2Sharp commit object with data like this

```
Message      : Further harden mutex closing process

MessageShort : Further harden mutex closing process
Encoding     : UTF-8
Author       : 
Committer    : 
Tree         : {.gitattributes, .gitignore, Build, Doc...}
Parents      : {fe26fc1a476f18bfa8a70c315fdbd96f1434d29c}
Notes        : {}
Id           : 1ba7bce90444a323fa9079cb06e5921afd0c3cd8
Sha          : 1ba7bce90444a323fa9079cb06e5921afd0c3cd8
Repository   : LibGit2Sharp.Repository
```

You need to invoke this with the 32-bit (x86) PowerShell.exe.

Comment: Why does this require the 32-bit version, and is there any way to do it without?

Comment: Note that with VS 2017, the might will be different for each installation depending on the edition of VS (community, enterprise,.. and released/preview), all of which can be installed side-by-side

Comment: Because this version of Visual Studio is 32-bit.